# what can be root cause for this behavior in Optimizing "Number of Islands" program using DFS recursive approach

Tags: c, recursion, optimization

I am having an issue in optimizing the "number of islands" program that I had downloaded from web. I tried optimizing it as explained below, but couldnt get it 100% right.

what is Number of islands ?

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-islands/

I have taken the below "c" program from one of the website for determining number of islands in a given graph.

```
void DFS(int M[][COL], int row, int col, bool visited[][COL])
{
   // These arrays are used to get row and column numbers of 8 neighbours 
   // of a given cell
   static int rowNbr[] = {-1, -1, -1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1};
   static int colNbr[] = {-1,  0,  1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1};

   int k = 0;
   // Mark this cell as visited
   visited[row][col] = true;
   printf("\n row=%d, col=%d", row, col); 

   // Recur for all connected neighbours
   for (k = 0; k < 8; ++k) {
       printf(" k=%d", k); 
       if (isSafe(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited) )
           DFS(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited);
   }
}

// The main function that returns count of islands in a given boolean
// 2D matrix
int countIslands(int M[][COL])
{
    // Make a bool array to mark visited cells.
    // Initially all cells are unvisited
    bool visited[ROW][COL];
    memset(visited, 0, sizeof(visited));

    // Initialize count as 0 and travese through the all cells of
    // given matrix
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0, j=0;
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; ++j) {
            if (M[i][j] && !visited[i][j]) // If a cell with value 1 is not
            {                         // visited yet, then new island found
               DFS(M, i, j, visited);     // Visit all cells in this island.
               ++count;                   // and increment island count
               printf("\n count is %d", count);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return count;
}


// A function to check if a given cell (row, col) can be included in DFS
int isSafe(int M[][COL], int row, int col, bool visited[][COL])
{
    // row number is in range, column number is in range and value is 1 
    // and not yet visited
    printf(" (i=%d, j=%d)", row, col);
    return (row >= 0) && (row < ROW) &&     
       (col >= 0) && (col < COL) &&      
       (M[row][col] && !visited[row][col]); 
}
```

As having two for loops for the full matrix size is not the best way of handling this problem, I tried optimizing as below.

In addition to rememeber what node I visited, I also manipulated the indexes "i" and "j" to further optimize and skipping the check for is_visited flag. Hope my explanation is clear. Code below.

```
// A utility function to do DFS for a 2D boolean matrix. It only considers
// the 8 neighbours as adjacent vertices
void DFS_new(int M[][COL], int *row, int *col, bool visited[][COL])
{
    // These arrays are used to get row and column numbers of 8 neighbours 
    // of a given cell
    int k;
    static int rowNbr[] = {-1, -1, -1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1};
    static int colNbr[] = {-1,  0,  1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1};

    // Mark this cell as visited
    visited[*row][*col] = true;
    printf("\n row=%d, col=%d", *row, *col); 
    // Recur for all connected neighbours
   for (k = 0; k < 8; ++k) 
   {
       printf(" k=%d", k); 
       if (isSafe(M, (*row) + rowNbr[k], (*col) + colNbr[k], visited) )
       {
           (*row) = (*row)+rowNbr[k];
           (*col) = (*col)+colNbr[k];
           DFS_new(M, row, col, visited);
       }
   }
}

// The main function that returns count of islands in a given boolean
// 2D matrix
int countIslands_new(int M[][COL])
{
   // Make a bool array to mark visited cells.
   // Initially all cells are unvisited
   bool visited[ROW][COL];
   memset(visited, 0, sizeof(visited)); 

    // Initialize count as 0 and travese through the all cells of
   // given matrix
   int count = 0;
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   while (i < ROW) 
   {
       j = 0;
       while (j < COL)
       {
           if (M[i][j] && !visited[i][j]) 
           {                              
               DFS_new(M, &i, &j, visited);
               count++;                    
              printf("\n count is %d", count);
           }
           j++;
       }
       i++;
   } 
   return count;
}
```

Now coming to the problem, If I use the below input for testing the above two programs, my code gives a wrong output. It indicates the number of islands are 4, where as actually there are only 3 islands. The original program works fine though.

```
// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    int M[][COL]= {  {1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
             {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
             {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
             {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
             {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}
          };

    printf("Number of islands is: %d\n", countIslands(M));

    return 0;
}
```

One particular thing that I observed for which I couldn't build the logic is as below.

In my program, I see that below code snippet from my program in function DFS_new is getting executed more than 8 times without this function getting called again (I mean without even recursive function getting called).

```
for (k = 0; k < 8; ++k) 
{
    printf(" k=%d", k); 
}
```

output of the printf below:

```
 row=4, col=0 k=0 (i=3, j=-1) k=1 (i=3, j=0) k=2 (i=3, j=1) k=3 (i=4, j=-1) 
 k=4 (i=4, j=1) k=5 (i=5, j=-1) **k=6** (i=5, j=0) **k=7** (i=5, j=1) 
 **k=6** (i=4, j=1) **k=7** (i=4, j=2)
```

Hope this question makes sense to this forum and expecting a positive response.

Comment: Debugger...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great anti-optimization.

Dereferencing pointers is actually slower than call by value for integral types.

Compilers know how to unroll and vectorize a loop of the form `for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {...}` if `i` is only **read** and never passed by reference inside the loop.

They are having trouble with loops of the form `while(i < k) {...; i++; ...}`, especially if `i` is passed as a non-`const` reference to some other function.

---

As for where your error is:

```
       (*row) = (*row)+rowNbr[k];
       (*col) = (*col)+colNbr[k];
```

You are modifying the actual integers in each loop iteration, and the offset for the neighbours is now cumulative instead of being sampled one after another.

Or in other words, you are no longer checking a square.

---

An actual optimization would had been to make the `static` offset tables full `const` instead (field of `const int`) and to remove all the debug output.

Use a flattened array (`bool M[ROW][COL]`) instead of an array of arrays (`bool M[][COL]`).

Be correct about `const` on parameters.

Use the `static` keyword on functions you don't plan to export to another compilation unit.

That allows the compiler to do the optimization, and it does much better than you could:

```
#include <cstring>

const int COL = 8;
const int ROW = 8;

// A function to check if a given cell (row, col) can be included in DFS
static int isSafe(const bool M[ROW][COL], const int row, const int col, const bool visited[ROW][COL])
{
    // row number is in range, column number is in range and value is 1 
    // and not yet visited
    return (row >= 0) && (row < ROW) &&     
       (col >= 0) && (col < COL) &&      
       (M[row][col] && !visited[row][col]); 
} 

static void DFS(const bool M[ROW][COL], const int row, const int col, bool visited[ROW][COL])
{
   // These arrays are used to get row and column numbers of 8 neighbours 
   // of a given cell
   const int rowNbr[] = {-1, -1, -1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1};
   const int colNbr[] = {-1,  0,  1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1};

   int k = 0;
   // Mark this cell as visited
   visited[row][col] = true;

   // Recur for all connected neighbours
   for (k = 0; k < 8; ++k) {
       if (isSafe(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited) )
           DFS(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited);
   }
}

// The main function that returns count of islands in a given boolean
// 2D matrix
int countIslands(const bool M[ROW][COL])
{
    // Make a bool array to mark visited cells.
    // Initially all cells are unvisited
    bool visited[ROW][COL];
    memset(visited, 0, sizeof(visited));

    // Initialize count as 0 and travese through the all cells of
    // given matrix
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0, j=0;
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; ++j) {
            if (M[i][j] && !visited[i][j]) // If a cell with value 1 is not
            {                         // visited yet, then new island found
               DFS(M, i, j, visited);     // Visit all cells in this island.
               ++count;                   // and increment island count
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Compile the "optimized" code e.g. with a recent CLANG 5.0 and `-O3`, and all the loops are gone in the assembly. Fully replaced with unrolled code or even just plain vector instructions: https://godbolt.org/g/SwxSn3

Comment: Really appreciate the effort. This is awesome. More than bug fix, I liked the extra information and background information you had provided.

Comment: And calling by value with scalar types also removes any aliasing problems to that value.